# IncompatibleClassChangeError when testing guava code with sbt

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, guava

I have a Java 1.6 + Scala 2.9.2 project using maven and sbt. The project started throwing this exception in the tests when I added the guava Cache classes:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: 
class com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder$3 has interface 
com.google.common.base.Ticker as super class
```

Doing `sbt clean compile` works perfectly but `sbt clean test` throws this exception.

The version of guava is 13.0

The module raising the exception has:

```scala
import com.google.common.cache.{CacheBuilder, Cache}
...
val cache: Cache[String, Integer] = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()  
     .maximumSize(5000).build()
```

My sbt dependencies are:

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scala-tools.testing" %% "scalacheck" % "1.9" % "test" changing(),
    "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.9" % "test"
)
```

And the maven dependencies are:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
      <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
      <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_2.9.1</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.novocode</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-interface</artifactId>
      <version>0.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ticker was changed from Interface to abstract class before Guava 13.

The fact that this happens in test but not compile is a good indicator.

I think an earlier version of Guava is ending up on your test classpath, probably as a transitive dependency.

You could try using [sbt-inspectr](https://github.com/eed3si9n/sbt-inspectr) to explore the test classpath and find out more, or you could try excluding, something like:

```
"org.scala-tools.testing" %% "scalacheck" % "1.9" % "test" changing(), excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "com.google.guava")
)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention `sbt run` threw the exception as well, so it was another dependency causing it.
Thanks for the `ExclusionRule` and `excludeAll`. sbt-inspectr didn't work as expected but using manually managed dependencies seems to solve the problem.